# How to know which version of pandas-profiling I'm using?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

I'm using **google colab** for programming. I just wanted to know which version of the pandas_profiling package I'm using.

I tried with the below options. None of them worked.

1. `pandas_profiling.__version__`
2. `pandas_profiling.version__version__`
3. `pandas.show_versions()`

I just want to let you know, I'm using pandas `1.0.3` version.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: After `import pandas as pd`, `pd.__version__` seems to return the current version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

can you try to run the following from colab to see if it works?

```
!pip freeze |grep pandas-profiling
```

Comment: Great! This worked. Can you let me know how this works, if possible?

Comment: 'pip freeze' list all installed packages and grep helps you find the line with pandas-profiling. Please accept the answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for explaining. I tried to accept already. It says need to wait for 2 minutes to accept. I hope there is a time limit. Will defnetly accept :) . Don't worry.